# Convert DataRow value to strongly typed value

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable, datarow

I want to convert a value from a DataRow to a strongly typed variable. I thought about something like:

```
int id = row.Field<int>("ID");
```

But the problem is, that our standard Db-Select returns a DataTable **where every value is type of string**. Means every value is object there and columns doesn't have specific type. By this `Field<T>` throws InvalidCastException because i try to cast object to int.

So i did something by my own:

```
    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);

        Type typ = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));

        if ((row != null) &&
            (row[columnName] != null) &&
            (!Convert.IsDBNull(row[columnName])))
        {
            if (typ == null)
            {
                returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName], typeof(T));
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName], typ);
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

This method works as expected. I can convert nullable values, strings and value types. Ok i need to catch exception if someone input bullshit like own types. But else it's fine.

But if i load a DataTable with 30000 rows and 20 Columns and want to use this method to convert each value for object creation i got huge performance lack. If iam using `int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);` and so on for each value it is 5-6 times faster then my general method. But i don't like to Convert them all manually especially if there are much `DBNull.Value`.

I think the problem is getting the underlying type by:

```
Type typ = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
```

This is reflaction call and slow down my method. Is this right? Is there someone who got the same problem and has a fast solution maybe?

**UPDATE:**

Our Standard-Select works like this:

```
DbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new DbDataAdapter();
dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

dataSet = new DataSet();

dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
dtReturn = dataSet.Tables[0].Copy();
```

DbDataAdapter internaly uses an OracleDataAdapter.

**UPDATE:**

For clarification iam doing the following (just small example):

i have a class which represents a select query. For example:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id{get;set}
  public string Name{get;set}
}
```

In Database (Oracle) i have a Table "Customer" which got 2 Columns `Id number(5)` and `Name varchar2(100)`.

Now i want to read all Customer and Convert them to Customer-Objects.
So i read the Data via our standard Routine SqlSelect. This returns me a DataTable. The intern of this method is posted before under first UPDATE.

Now i loop over every DataRow in this DataTable and Convert this Cell value for Object creation.

```
List<Customer> myList = new List<Customer>();
foreach (DataRow row in SqlSelect())
{
  Customer customer = new Customer();
  customer.Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]);
  customer.Name = Convert.ToString(row["NAME"]);
  myList.Add(customer);
}
```

This would be fine in this way. But i want to convert like:

```
customer.Id = row.ConvertTo<int>("ID");
```

If my DataTable at row["ID"] would be int the Field Method can handle this well. Especialy if there are other columns which can be null etc. But in my case the row["ID"] (and all other values of every select) is string. So Field can't cast this. My ConvertTo does it but has huge performance lack on large tables.

Comment: Use a profiler. Why would *we* know where your CPU is spending its time? Also, there's *no* point in using `Convert`. Either the value is `DBNull.Value`, or it is of type `T` - just do a simple cast.

Comment: Your _"standard DB select returns typeless DataTable"_? How is that possible? How do you fill that table? Normally the `DataAdapter` retrieves schema informations from the datareader. _"i don't like to Convert them all manually especially if there are much `DBNull.Value`"_. What's the problem with `DBNull.Value`? `DataRow.Field` supports nullable types.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i won't have a problem with DBNull.Value if i could use the Field<T> Method. It's just much afford if i convert each value with Convert.ToInt32() and so on. But the Field<T> Method  doesn't work as explained above.

Comment: @Sebi: why do you copy the whole table before you return it? If you don't need the filled `DataSet` for a different purpose you can `return dataSet.Tables[0]`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for this hint. I don't developed this routine. It's our standard which is developed by a collegue. I will ask him...

Comment: @Sebi: you use `DataAdapter.Fill` which automatically creates the columns with the correct type. But a `DataTable` is not strongly typed so you need to cast the values to the correct type. So the question is still not clear. Can you show the code where you use `ConvertTo`? Maybe that helps to clarify your task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do here is very strange. You have to understand, that all datatypes in the C# inherit from object. So int, int?, char, double, class MyClass, struct MyStruct, they all inherit from object.

So row[columnName] contains data of type int, then even if it is returning object, it is possible to directly cast to int.

```
int i = (int)row[columnName]; //when int data,
```

The exception here is, when the data are DBNUll, has to be tested before casting. **There is really no need for the Convert class, because it is playing heavily with reflection what is source of the performance loss!**

**EDIT[1]: @Scott Chamberlain is right, I improved the code to make it safer for value types:**

```
public static class IsNullable<T>
{
    private static readonly Type type = typeof(T);
    private static readonly bool is_nullable = type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
    public static bool Result { get { return is_nullable; } }
}


 public static class Extension
 {
     public static T CastColumnData<T>(this DataRow row,
                                       string columnName)
    {
        object obj;
        if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("row is null");
        if ((obj = row[columnName]) == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("row[" + columnName + "]  is null");
        bool is_dbnull = obj == DBNull.Value;
        if (is_dbnull && !IsNullable<T>.Result) throw new InvalidCastException("Columns data are DbNull, but the T[" + typeof(T).ToString() + "] is non nullable value type");
        return is_dbnull ? default(T) : (T)obj;
     }
 }
```

Class Convert is here for something else, for creating equivalent value between two datatypes, that share something in common, but here it is pretty heavy stuff using lots of reflection.

object and int are not equivalent, the object is inherited by the int, even when not directly...

**EDIT[2]: New updates to original question finally clarified, that all columns types are actually strings, not different kind of data types, and they have to be transformed/parsed to the requsted data types.**

I am afraid, that there is no faster solution, as value types do not implement Parse and TryParse from interface with generic type. They are static methods and that makes the attempt to solve this by generics pretty problematic.

Comment: I always am wary of returning `default(T)` for things like int's, I don't like not having a way to tell the difference between 0 and DbNull. If the class is not nullable it usually a safer choice to throw a exception. Your code is fine for nullable types (`Nullable<T>` structs and classes), just non nullable types I would not trust it.

Comment: @ipavlu iam sorry the values stored in DataTable are not object. They are all string. I correct this in my question. The Field<T> Method can't convert a string to int. The Method expects that the DataColumn is from type int too. The innerhitence from object is quite clear.

Comment: @Sebi: they are only strings if you store only strings in your database. Then you have bigger problems than performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are not only strings in the Database :D this would be horror indeed. But if i use this GetType() on Cell of DataTable i always get string. I think i need to research our db methods...

Comment: @Sebi: maybe the select converts it to `varchar` or you have omitted code where someone uses `row["column].ToString()` instead of using `row.Field<int>("column")`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i updated my question to clarify what iam talking about. Can't explain myself why all values in DataTable are string if you say dataAdapter.Fill should type it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, you are right, I a have improved to code to make it clean for value types too...

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want? If errors are frequent there'll be overheard catching them, but if not I don't see that being a problem. The Convert.ChangeType probably uses reflection under the scenes so that may be a bit slow also...

```
public static T ConvertTo<T>( this DataRow dataRow, string columnName )
{
    var defaultValue = default( T );

    var valueOfCell = GetCellValue(dataRow, columnName);

    if ( defaultValue == null && valueOfCell == null )
    {
        return default( T );
    }

    try
    {
        return ( T )Convert.ChangeType( valueOfCell, typeof( T ) );
    }
    catch ( InvalidCastException ex )
    {
        return default( T );
    }
}
```